# Does anyone know what plane this is?

Tags: aircraft-identification, fighter

I have looked at hundreds of photos on line but nothing that has the upswept wings and the downswept rear wings with just one tail.  I'd like to see a picture so I can paint it properly - thanks

Comment: Pleasse update your question with a picture by using the [edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/72974/edit) link

Comment: Help us help you...  Is this an aircraft you read a description of, or have you seen one in person?  Do you have a photo?  Have you Googled "F-4" to see if that is the one you are thinking or?  If you don't provide us some feedback I am going to vote to close as too broad.

Answer (score 4):

A fighter with "upswept wings and the downswept rear wings with just one tail"? sounds like an [F-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II).

BTW, "upswept" is called a ["dihedral"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_(aeronautics)), and "downswept" is an ["anhedral"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_(aeronautics)#Anhedral).

Comment: F-4 is pretty much the only plane fitting the description, allthough only the outer part of F-4's wings were "upswept".